# Ревизия в БД

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, база-данных, sql, mysql

Есть таблица с большим (а может, точнее излишним) количеством столбцов. Как одним sql-запросом удалить столбцы, в которых нет ни одного значения. Массив данных и количество таблиц  в базе данных не позволяют провести эту работу вручную. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну так напишите все php. Первым запросом найдите пустые столбцы, потом ещё одним поудаляйте те, где нет данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удаление столбца можно сделать при помощи следующей конструкции:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP field_name
```

где

`table_name` - имя таблицы, в которой будет удален столбец;
`field_name` - имя удаляемого столбца.

```
$sql="ALTER TABLE search DROP id_num";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Если мы хотим удалить сразу несколько полей, то надо через запятую повторить `DROP field_name` для каждого столбца:

```
$sql="ALTER TABLE search DROP id_1, DROP id_2, DROP id_3";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать как-то так, сгенерить скрипты таким образом и их выполнить. Не совсем уверен насчёт синтаксиса IF, но думаю, сможете найти, как правильно. Общая идея, чтобы основываясь на таблице  `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` сгенерировать нужные скрипты посредством SQL.

```
SELECT CONCAT('IF ( select count(*) from ',t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`,'`.`',t.`TABLE_NAME`,'` where `',t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`,'`.`',t.`TABLE_NAME`,'`.`',t.COLUMN_NAME,'` is null) = ( select count(*) from ',t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`,'`.`',t.`TABLE_NAME`,'`) THEN \n ALTER TABLE `', t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, '`.`', t.`TABLE_NAME`, '` drop column `',t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`,'`.`',t.`TABLE_NAME`,'`.`',t.COLUMN_NAME,'`;\n END IF;') as sqlcode
  FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` t
 WHERE 1
   AND t.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'you_db_name'
 ORDER BY 1
```